# total number of permutations of numbers 1, 2,…,9 where all the even numbers precede all the odd numbers

Tags: math, mathematical-optimization

essentially I'm not sure how to find the number of permutations something has.

Would really appreciate if someone could go through the steps of finding the total number of permutations.

Thank you so much!

Comment: As a hint, any such permutation can be formed by pairing a permutation of (2, 4, 6, 8) and a permutation of (1, 3, 5, 7, 9).

Comment: thanks, however I'm not too sure what you mean by paring a permutation

Comment: Try writing out some example permutations meeting your requirements and see if you notice anything.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. The issue is I'm not working out the number of permutations, even for the subsets of the numbers correctly.

Comment: Can you work out the number of permutations of, say, (1,2,3,4,5)?

Comment: n! (n−r)! - 5!(5-1)! = 120

Comment: Please post mathematics questions to https://math.stackexchange.com instead of here.  This site is for programming, not math.

Answer (score 3):

If all even numbers come before the odds, the starting 4 positions should be occupied by the even numbers and the last 5 positions should be occupied by the odd numbers. In other words, you have 9 positions to fill with 9 different numbers. You'll have to fill the starting 4 positions with even and the rest with odd.

Now,

**Number of ways to fill the starting 4 positions with even = 4! = 1*2*3*4 = 24**
**Number of ways to fill other 5 positions with odd = 5! = 1*2*3*4*5 = 120**

**So, final answer is 4! * 5! = 24*120 = 2880**